# cubic spline interpolation in Modelica

Tags: modelica

I have a set of data which I have to interpolate. My first data set contains z1[:] values for every x1[:] and y1[:]. I have to interpolate my second data set x2[:], y2[:] w.r.t to my first set to get z2[:] values. The size of my first data set is different from second data set. Is there any algorithm already written in Modelica for this functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interpolation on irregular grids was already requested by https://trac.modelica.org/Modelica/ticket/1153#comment:15 but still is not part of the Modelica Standard Library (as of version 3.2.2 of today).

Comment: So, the only way I could solve it is to write an algorithm for bilinear interpolation. Am I right?

Comment: Bilinear interpolation (on a regular grid though) already is part of the Modelica Standard Library by block CombiTable2D.